# Add wdContentControlDropdownList to range in table

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to add the below object is a nightmare. I would like to add the dropdown to a cell range on a table in word

```
Dim objCC As ContentControl 
Dim objMap As XMLMapping 

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList) 
objCC.Title = "Select" 
objCC.SetPlaceholderText , , "Please Select" 

'List entries 
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Yes" 
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Nam" 

otable.Cell(2, 1).Select
selection = objCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify where you want to add the Content Control when you add it to the document:

```
Sub test()

    Dim oCC As ContentControl
    Dim oCCMapp As XMLMapping
    Dim oCCRange As Range

    Set oCCRange = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range

    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList, oCCRange)

End Sub
```